# How to send embed to direct message in Discord?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm catching embed from a server, and I want to forward embed to direct message.

So I get embed like this:

```
@client.event                                              
async def on_message(message):
    embed = message.embeds[0]
```

Now I fixed the embed so they are sendable to DM. Cause they are in a bad format.

I tried send to a channel 'embed' with a requests.post with Webhook and It works.

When I tried to send 'embed' to DM it do not works.

```
webhook_url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/users/{}/{}'.format(user_id, token_bot)

def sendToDiscord(webhook_url, embed):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    response = requests.post(webhook_url, data= embed, headers=headers)
    return response
```

So the real problem is how to send via requests POST an embed?

Comment: Why not use `client.send_message` to send the embeds to the channel?

Comment: because it is in another format

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to send embeds to a user's direct message

```
@bot.event                                              
async def on_message(message):
   emb=discord.Embed(title='Hello',description='Test message')
   emb.add_field(name='Name of field',value='The value for the field')
   await bot.send_message(,embed=emb)
```

Another method is to use the `whisper` function

```
@bot.event                                              
async def on_message(message):
    emb=discord.Embed(title='Hello',description='Test message')
    emb.add_field(name='Name of field',value='The value for the field')
    await bot.whisper(embed=emb)
```